# How do I compile the msm android kernel using the AOSP toolchain?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, x86-64, android-source, android-kernel

I've been stuck at this for more than a week, so I'd appreciate any help.

**What am I trying to do? (you can skip this part if you want)**

I'm trying to do android kernel exploitation. That's not my current problem though. To learn kernel exploitation, I need to be able to get a version of android that is vulnerable to a certain vulnerability. So here's what I'm doing:

1. Going [here](https://source.android.com/security/bulletin/2020-10-01) to select a CVE that I want to learn how to exploit
2. After selecting a CVE, I need to select a build that is vulnerable to that CVE from [here](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers#source-code-tags-and-builds)
3. Now that I have chosen a build (`QQ3A.200805.001` in my case), I note its branch name (`android-10.0.0_r41` in my case)
4. Now I need to be able to run this build in the android emulator (qemu) once as a production build, and once with KASAN+KCOV+debugging symbols for gdb

**Before I begin, I'm following these guides:**

1. https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/kasan-kcov
2. https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels-deprecated
3. Google :)

**My Setup:**

I did this to download everything I need:

```sh
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm
cd msm
git fetch --all --tags --prune
git checkout remotes/origin/android-msm-coral-4.14-android10
cd ..

mkdir AOSP
cd AOSP
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
repo sync -j`nproc`
repo init -b android-10.0.0_r41
repo sync -j`nproc`
cd ..
```

When I went to the AOSP directory and tried compiling with:

```sh
source ./build/envsetup.sh
lunch aosp_flame-userdebug # For the Pixel 4
m
```

It compiled in 4 hours, but it worked.

**My First Issue:**

I then created this bash script in the main folder to try to compile the msm kernel normally (without KASAN/KCOV):

```sh
###########
# Params: #
###########
ARCH=arm64
CONFIG=cuttlefish_defconfig

###########
# Script: #
###########
read -p "Compile with clang instead of gcc? [y/N] " USE_CLANG

if [ $USE_CLANG == y ] || [ $USE_CLANG == Y ]; then
        COMPILER=clang
        CC_PATH=$(pwd)/AOSP/prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-r346389c/bin/
else
        COMPILER=gcc
        CC_PATH=$(pwd)/AOSP/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/
        export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-android-
fi

export ARCH=$ARCH
export PATH=$PATH:$CC_PATH

cd msm
make clean
make distclean
make $CONFIG
make CC=$COMPILER
```

When I run it with GCC, I get bombarded with depreciation warnings and I get an error:

```
Android GCC has been deprecated in favor of Clang, and will be removed from
Android in 2020-01 as per the deprecation plan in:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/+/master/GCC_4_9_DEPRECATION.md

...

Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler
```

When I run it with clang, I also get a ton of warnings and this error:

```
./arch/arm64/include/asm/stack_pointer.h:8:51: error: register 'sp' unsuitable for global register variables on this target
register unsigned long current_stack_pointer asm ("sp");

...

In file included from ./include/linux/kvm_host.h:14:
./include/linux/signal.h:81:11: warning: array index 3 is past the end of the array (which contains 1 element) [-Warray-bounds]
return (set->sig[3] | set->sig[2] |
```

Full outputs for the script can be found [here (for gcc)](https://0bin.net/paste/PB9Tnxey#XVNqv0B6dGQDqKJkYbpv9twZ3FKQI9RU93oYhvC8ewe) and [here (for clang)](https://0bin.net/paste/k4NF6D9E#QRv50pU1xNClA1PjxGvuRHLJV8LvnPL9HN2c8xq5SUa). Basically my first issue is that I don't know why I'm getting these compilation errors. So any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**My Second Issue:**
Now,  I am checking out the `remotes/origin/android-msm-coral-4.14-android10` branch in the [msm repo](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+refs), but I think this isn't the way to go because I need the kernel version that corresponds to a certain build/branch (`QQ3A.200805.001` or `android-10.0.0_r41` in my case). I think I need to build the exact version that is precompiled in the AOSP repository.

For example, if I go to the `AOSP/device/google/coral` directory, and run `git log`, I get something like this:

```
commit 62d311ad7cfc3e76a5278634427596462069b44d (HEAD, tag: android-10.0.0_r41, tag: m/android-10.0.0_r41, aosp/android10-qpr3-release)
Merge: 7b91fff 0657c80
Author: android-build-team Robot <android-build-team-robot@google.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 10 23:45:11 2020 +0000

    Merge cherrypicks of [11827366, 11829660, 11829049, 11829662, 11829647, 11829300, 11826697, 11829719, 11829051, 11829663, 11829664, 11829838, 11829052, 11829472, 11829586] into qt-qpr3-release
   
    Change-Id: Ic126de75c24133f8d43df7c9d8f09059a9ca8089

commit 0657c80f016720f70ed6f9618f928a30e71f2b79
Author: wenchangliu <wenchangliu@google.com>
Date:   Tue Mar 24 18:11:18 2020 +0800

    coral: Add seccomp policy for Codec2 process
   
    Add seccomp policy for Codec2 process.
   
    Bug: 149511958
    Test: adb shell killall media.hwcodec
    Change-Id: Iab64bd42ead0c5a27769a757007282c2dddf911d
    (cherry picked from commit 3628a510a808a52c4ebf69958a8343928e5df3f2)
    (cherry picked from commit 45a6093f3d085ca2a531c2607bd12dbc1eff6bf9)

commit 7b91fffc14afb41cf14772566272c72b37c36785
Merge: 2e7f1a3 e8c9484
Author: android-build-team Robot <android-build-team-robot@google.com>
Date:   Wed Jun 10 00:37:23 2020 +0000

...
```

Link for this exact commit/tag can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/device/google/coral/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r41). However, there is no `android-10.0.0_r41` tag in the [msm source repo](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+refs), so I don't know which version of the msm repo corresponds to the prebuilt one in the AOSP directory. And.. I don't know where to start looking tbh.

**Any help is greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Check [Build Kernels section of source.android.com](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building-kernels)?

Comment: I saw it before, but I couldn't find a `build/build.sh` script in the msm repo. Also, I met this issue when compiling it: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/why-cant-i-compile-the-msm-android-kernel.4235027/ (this is also my thread)

Comment: Did you found something to proceed with ? Apparently I also ended up needing the same requirement

Comment: Apparently you can't run the msm kernel in an emulator, you have to run it on a physical device, so I switched to cuttlefish instead (which meets my needs)

Answer (score 0):

Try [vortex-clang](https://github.com/vijaymalav564/vortex-clang)

Or [proton-clang](https://github.com/kdrag0n/proton-clang)

How I compile

Example for vortex-clang...

```
export PATH="$HOME/toolchains/vortex-clang/bin:$PATH"  
export ARCH=arm64
export CC=clang
export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
export CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32=arm-linux-gnueabi-
```

In my case I get an error and to fix it:

```
export LD="$HOME/toolchains/vortex-clang/bin/ld.lld
```

And just generate your configuration and Compile

Creating your configuration

```
make you_defconfig -j($nproc)
```

Compiling the kernel

```
make -j($nproc)
```

Comment: And you also need the package: gnutils-linux-gnu

Comment: Please note that you can [edit] your post. Please use that to make this one more obviously according to [answer].